# Why does jQuery.change() only trigger when I leave the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charactercount

I have a textarea element and I want to print the number of characters written, above the textarea, as I'm typing. The HTML looks like this:

```
<p id="counter"></p>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

and the javascript:

```
jQuery( "#text" ).change( function(){
    var numberOfChars = jQuery( "#text" ).val().length;
    jQuery( "#counter" ).html( numberOfChars );
});
```

But the counter only "updates" when I click outside the textarea. Why is that? I want the counter to update on the fly as I'm writing.

Comment: Just to note where this behaviour is specified: *The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus* [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents)

Comment: @lonesomeday Then it makes sense now. Tnx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is known behaviour of the change event. It does not fire until the element has lost focus. [From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

I would bind the script to the keyup instead (you could use the other key events, but up makes the most sense in this context):

```
jQuery( "#text" ).keyup(function(){
    var numberOfChars = jQuery( "#text" ).val().length;
    jQuery( "#counter" ).html( numberOfChars );
});
```

Comment: Well.. That was easy. Thanks! But do you have any idea why jQuery.change() behaved like onblur instead of onchange?

Comment: It is expected behaviour. I have edited my answer to be more complete

Comment: @MildFuzz Please avoid using link-shortening services: there's no need to do it, so all it serves to do is to obfuscate where the link points.

Comment: keyup doesn't trigger if the user uses the mouse to paste in some info

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input#myId').bind('input', function() {
  //some code
});
```

It allows to detect keyup event, paste data with the mouse...

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead of **change**. See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ren4A/1/

Answer (score 1):

try .on('keyup') or .on('keypress') or .on('keydown')