# Alternative to .change() for specific situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**What I want to achieve:**

I have a text box that uses jquery ui autocomplete function, and what I want to achieve is when an option is clicked on and selected from the autocomplete dropdown I want an event to be triggered.

**The problem**

The problem I'm having is, I tried to use .change() which works however this only triggers when you click off the element. (This problem has been asked before in this post [Why does jQuery.change() only trigger when I leave the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567824/why-does-jquery-change-only-trigger-when-i-leave-the-element)).

However the solutions in  that thread are of no use to me in this situation. As I want the event to be triggered when the element from the drop down is selected and loaded into the text box. I don't want to have to click out of the text box to trigger the .change() event.

**The ideal outcome:**

When the user selects an option from the autocomplete list it then triggers the event without the user having to click away from the text box.

The event in question I want to occur is the autocomplete text box is hidden once the user selects an option:

```
$(search_box).change( function () {
    $(search_box).hide();
} );
```

This works but as i've mentioned above the user has to click away for the change event to trigger. Is there any work around to this?

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `autocompleteselect` event handler as
`$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {} );`
which is

> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu. The default action
>   is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected
>   item.

[here](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Your a champ! Thanks very much you deserve your answer and upvote! I did not realise this was possible, unfortunately I am still getting to grips with jquery and jquery ui and for some reason I didn't think to check the documentation!

Comment: Glad to know that I could help. A tip, whenever you decide to use any library/framework, the first things you should read is the documentation whenever you are stuck somewhere

Comment: Your right, sometimes It can be daunting due to the the way they are written, but once you get the hand of it then its not so bad, like the php documentation I found really difficult to read at first. But practice makes perfect! Thanks again.